# TypeError: <Class Name> is not a constructor but has been used before

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

I have this code:

```js
//Interpreter.js

class Interpreter {
    constructor() {
        this.data = "data";
    }

    ...
}

module.exports = Interpreter;

//index.js

const Interpreter = require('./interpreter/Interpreter');
...
var interpreter = new Interpreter();

// File.js
const Interpreter = require('./Interpreter');
...
var interpreter = new Interpreter();
```

When I make initialize the interpreter in File.js it gives me the error:

```
TypeError: Interpreter is not a constructor
```

Why am I getting this error and how could I fix it?

Please help, Thank you.

Comment: you get above error in both `index.js` and `file.js`?

Comment: just in file.js.

Comment: Do you export the `Interpreter` class?

Comment: Yes I do. @RahulKumar

Comment: Are `index.js` and `File.js` in the same directory…?

Comment: @deceze no File.js is located  with Interpreter.js 1 sec fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

In `index.js`, `Interpreter` refers to the *module* `Interpreter.js`, not to the class defined inside that module. You can't even access the class, because it's not exported in any way.

To export the `Interpreter` class as the default export from the module:

```js
//Interpreter.js
...
module.export = Interpreter;
```

This should make the rest of the code work as is.

If you need to export more things from `Interpreter.js`, export them as an object assigned to `module.exports`:

```js
//Interpreter.js
...
module.exports = { Interpreter };
```

Then import it using object destructuring, like this:

```js
const { Interpreter } = require('./Interpreter');
```

Comment: My mistake. I did export it. Sorry for the misunderstanding.